# Installing python on Mac not working

Tags: python, numpy, installation, failed-installation

I want to install numpy on python. However every time I try to download it this happens -

> sams-mbp:~ staaghol$ pip3 install numpy
>   -bash: /Users/untitled/anaconda/bin/pip3: No such file or directory

I deleted anaconda but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using just 'pip'

Comment: I recommend trying pip3.x, pip alone should map to OSX's Python 2 install - unless, of course that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you want but I use the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) Python:

```
$ brew install python3
$ brew linkapps python3
$ pip3 install numpy
```

N.B. Of course you have to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) first, you can follow the instructions on their website.